# Weird gap between <div> element and its <video> child

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html5-video, html5-audio

I´ve wrote a small HTML and CSS program to dinamically resize <video> and <audio> elements while changing viewport size. So I used flexbox and avoided fixed width and height lenghts. Everything is fine, but I can get rid of a small bottom gap between the <video> and its <div> container, despite the same code works 100% with <audio> element. Its not padding and margin issue, since I normalize them to 0 at the beggining of CSS code. I wonder if it is not something about the render of the videoplayer.

The HTML code is here (prety simple):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos-parent.css">

    <title>MY WEBPAGE</title>
</head>

<body>

    <header>WELCOME TO MY WEBPAGE</header>

    <div id="flex-row">
        <div id="div-video-size">
            <video controls>
                <source src="video2.webm" type="video/webm">
                <source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support this type of video.
            </video>
        </div>


        <div id="div-audio-size">
            <audio controls>
                <source src="som2.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
                <source src="som2.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
                Your browser does not support this type of audio.
            </audio>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

and CSS is here. I used only part of the full viewport  size to render both <audio> and <video> elements, but I don´t think this has a role in the issue.

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
header {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
}

#flex-row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    width: 50%;
}

#div-video-size {
    width: 70%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#div-audio-size {
    width: 30%;
    height: 15%;

}

video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

audio {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I added the

```
object-fit: cover;
```

as a possible solution presented here in other questions but it didn´t help

I took a picture of this small gap and even asking to fill 100% of the div container, the gap is there. I place a small padding to the left of the <div> that contains the video element (green strip) but all the other sides are 0 for margin and padding. I really don´t know how to fully fil the video <div> container space.

[image]

I tried to fill the container space with the expected attributes like height: 100% and width:100% and I expected video element to fill the whole area of the container,as it did for audio element.

Comment: looks alike `padding-right: 10px;` is applied as written in the css

Comment: display: block to the video